# Не проксирует запрос с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

сервер на адресе http://localhost:8081 не принимает продолжение "/bots/ke/". Ошибка 502

```
location ~ ^/bots/ke/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/$1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
```

Comment: Если в адресе будет `/bots/ke/123`, то запрос должен будет проброшен до `http://localhost:8081/123`, правильно?

Comment: пока не суть, проблема в том, что не пробрасывается

Comment: 2020/11/27 16:12:30 [error] 8838#8838: *3 no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /bots/ke/blablabla HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Answer (score 0):

Заменить localhost на 127.0.0.1